# Responsive Container, but Images don't take up full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm looking to recreate the effect here on images 2 and 3: http://www.jessicahische.is/illustrating/penguinsinbathingsuits

These images obviously have "padding" filled in already by the image itself, but I was wondering if this effect is possible with just jQuery and CSS?

Any help or insight would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for centering items. Try something like this:

```
.box {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:center;
}


.center_item {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
```

And the corresponding HTML.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="center_item">Put your image here.</div>
</div>
```

What this does is simply puts a container around whatever you need to be centered. By using margin:0 auto; you can center any item within it's parent. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

## [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uxoviy/edit#javascript,html,live)

In this example, we use `text-align:center;` for our element `#gallery`
and force the image to be `100%` height. 
Than with *jQuery* we check that image on `.load()` to see if the image width exceeds the gallery width. In that case we'll change the width and vertical-center-alignment with jQuery. E.g:

CSS:

```
  #gallery{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    text-align:center;
  }
  #gallery img{
    height:100%;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#gallery img').load(function(){
  
  img = $(this);
  imgW = img.width();
  
  if(imgW > $('#gallery').width()){
    img.css({width:'100%', height:'auto'});
    img.css({marginTop: $('#gallery').height()/2 - $(this).height()/2 });
  }
 
});
```

Play with the images widths/heights to see how they respond.